# Leave 2 pricing table instead of 4 and center them?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, web-inspector

and sorry for my noobness, I am pretty new in the sphere!!

I have the following issue :

Here I have 4 pricing tables :

[4 pricing tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGNmS.png)

But when I just delete the code of 2 pricing tables to leave only 2 in the middle (it came from a template) its messy and looks like that :
[Looks like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVKqd.png)

I would like to center it.
How can I do please?

This is the code of the pricing tables :

```
  <!-- Price Start -->
    <section class="section bg-light" id="price">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-12 text-center">
                    <div class="section-title">
                        <h4 class="title text-uppercase fw-normal mb-4">Our <span class="text-primary fw-bold">Pricing</span> </h4>
                        <p class="text-muted mx-auto para-desc mb-0">Splash your dream color Bring your home to lively Colors. We make it a priotity to offer flexible services to accomodate your needs</p>
                    </div>
                </div><!--end col-->
            </div><!--end row-->

            <div class="row">
               
                
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mt-4 pt-2">
                    <div class="pricing-table shadow rounded business-plan position-relative bg-white text-center">
                        <h5 class="pricing-plan rounded-top text-uppercase bg-primary text-light p-4 mb-0">Стандарт пакет</h5>
                        <div class="price-value p-4 text-center position-relative">
                            <div class="price-lable rounded-pill">
                                <h4 class="mt-4 d-block">€640</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--end price value-->                             
                        <div class="pricing-features">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
                                <li>Консультация</li>
                                <li>Помощь в выборе вузов</li>
                                <li>Польский присяжный перевод на территории Польши</li>
                                <li>Онлайн регистрация</li>
                                <li>Переписка с вузами и уточнение всех вопросов</li>
                                <li>100% результат поступления</li>
                                <li>Поселение в подходящее для вас жилье</li>
                                <li>Консультация о финансах во время учебы</li>
                                
                            <div class="price-button p-4">
                                <!-- <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill">Buy Now</a>                                         -->
                            </div><!--end button-->
                        </div><!--end price features-->
                    </div><!--end table-->
                </div><!--end col-->
                
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mt-4 pt-2">
                    <div class="pricing-table shadow rounded bg-white text-center">
                        <h5 class="pricing-plan rounded-top text-uppercase bg-light p-4 mb-0">Пакет VIP</h5>
                        <div class="price-value p-4 text-center position-relative">
                            <div class="price-lable rounded-pill">
                                <h4 class="mt-4 d-block">????</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--end price value-->                            
                        <div class="pricing-features">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
                                <li>включает в себя пакет “Стандарт”е</li>
                                <li>Мы встретим вас в аэропорту или на вокзале</li>
                                <li>Поможем при поселении</li>
                                <li>составим для вас персональную ознакомительную Программу</li>
                                <li>Совершим визит в пункт обмена валюты;</li>
                                <li>Визит в торговый центр с целью осуществления бытовых и продуктовых покупок;</li>
                                <li>Ознакомим с правилами пользования общественным транспортом;</li>
                                <li>Сопроводим и познакомим с ВУЗом: визит в деканат, оформление студенческого билета, определение группы, получение плана занятий.</li>
                                <li>Открытие банковского счета (по желанию);</li>

                            
                           
            </div><!--end row-->
        </div><!--end container-->
    </section><!--end section-->
    <!-- Price End -->
```

I think its done with bootstrap, I am not very good with it but my thoughts its that its something in bootstrap.min.css maybe?

Comment: Could you please provide the relevant html source of that page?

Comment: Hi Alex, you should be able to click the <div class="container"> to highlight that element and all of the child elements it contains, then copy and paste that into a Code Sample here on StackOverflow (the "{ }" button in the text editor).

Comment: Hello, its done! I have added it !

Answer (score 0):

Try to use class="mx-auto" with your current column.

For example, I've taken an example of a card here.

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row ">
   <div class="col-lg-3 mx-auto">
      <div class="card">
         <div class="card-header">Header</div>
         <div class="card-body">Content</div>
         <div class="card-footer">Footer</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello. it did not help, it gave me something even more large and not esthetic :(

Comment: Okay... Lots of issue in your code, Kindly send me the desire output...
I'll send you the code.